# Градиент поверх картинки

Tags: html, css, img, style

Почему градиент поверх картинки не появляется?

HTML код:

```
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#230051">
    <title>EmilAhmaServer – Главная</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/image/icon.png" type="image/png">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header" align="center">
      <img src="image/banner.png" width="100%">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS код:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#header:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 40%);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для `:before` необходимо задать свойство `content` со значением `''`.

```
content: '';
```

Это необходимо, т.к псевдоэлементы `:before` и `:after` работают в связке со свойством `content`. Если его не указать, то псевдоэлемент в DOM не появится.

Comment: А почему его необходимо задавать?

Comment: Потому-что псевдоэлементы  не имеют никакой разметки, поэтому задаётся content. Пока вы не задали ему хотя бы пустое поле, его как бы и не существует, а значит стили были даны несуществующему элементу.

Comment: @ΝNL993 без свойства `content` псевдоэлемента в DOM не будет. Они работают в связке.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи я в курсе, у меня множество ответов на CSS, где участвуют псевдо элементы. Я написал комментарий, чтобы отметить что ответ, не имеет вообще никакого объяснения, почему, что и как. (То есть отметить то, что он низкокачественный)

Comment: @marselbairam читайте комментарий выше.

Comment: @ΝNL993 дополнил ответ, спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score 0):

Так надо было сделать да? @ΝNL993

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#header:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
.tipo-kartinka {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#230051">
    <title>EmilAhmaServer – Главная</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/image/icon.png" type="image/png">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header" align="center">
      <div class="tipo-kartinka"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Да именно так и нужно было сделать, но я в вашем ответе не вижу никакого смысла, т.к. это просто дубликат ответа от @marselbairam, да ещё и также не имеющий никакого объяснения. (Хоть у вас в ответе и есть воспроизводимый пример, это не значит что ответ другой)

Comment: @ΝNL993 Вопрос - "Почему градиент поверх картинки не появляется?". Вам ответили же и пример вот с решением написал, что ещё нужно? marselbairam уже ответил на вопрос, но вам я думал нужно прям готовое решение, а не подсказка - сделал. Что ещё нужно ответить на ваш вопрос?

Comment: [Из справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): `Любой ответ, который направляет спрашивающего в нужное русло, является ценным. Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. Изложите свои предложения. Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше.`. Ответ который дан до вас, вполне соответствует стандартам StackOverflow на русском.